# Python For Loop DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, beautifulsoup

see below the following code I have at the moment and the error that is coming with it.

```
 companynames = []
for x in urls:
    website_nametext = requests.get(x)
    all_text = website_nametext.text
    all_soup = BeautifulSoup(all_text, 'html.parser')
    companynames.append(all_soup.h1.get_text())
overall_data = pd.DataFrame(data=[companynames], columns=['Company Name'])
```

I receive the following error

```
AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns
```

If I was to change the code to put three columns then it allows the dataframe to be created. See below the code.

```
    companynames = []
for x in urls:
    website_nametext = requests.get(x)
    all_text = website_nametext.text
    all_soup = BeautifulSoup(all_text, 'html.parser')
    companynames.append(all_soup.h1.get_text())
overall_data = pd.DataFrame(data=[companynames], columns=['Company Name', 'Company Name', 'Company Name'])
```

However I want the results 'x' , 'y' and 'z' to be in one column and each name on a separate row. rather than there being three separate columns as per my initial code however obviously that is creating an error.

How do I do so?

Comment: Did you mean `data=companynames`?

Comment: Can you show what `companynames` looks like? Hard to tell what to do but you can try to flatten it with more_itertools

Comment: When you print (companynames) this is the output -- ['Etimex ', 'Comptage Immobilier Services (CIS) ', 'Salter Housewares ']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out the square brackets around companynames in the pd.DataFrame call. With the brackets there it is a list of lists, albeit only one, but it effectively turns it through 90 degrees.